# Android, ExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener() does not work with registerForContextMenu() for childs

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView that it works brilliant when I click on it's children but when I set registerForContextMenu() for inner `View` that creates in `getChildView` in Adapter, `setOnChildClickListener` doesn't work.

If I set registerForContextMenu(mExpandable) it will work even for `Group` but I need it only for `Child`.

Answer (score 0):

`isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)` which in turn returns false default when we implement. Since it is false, we are unable to get respond OnChildClickListener.

Make the return value to true for isChildSelectable method.

For more info: [Solutions for ExpandableListView](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2014/05/android-custom-navigation-drawer-using.html)

I hope it will help you in solving your problem